# How to get user posts through facebook-sdk python api?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use facebook-jssdk to authorize my application for read access to user profile and user posts.

```
FB.login(
    function(response) { },  
    {scope:'user_status,user_likes,user_photos,user_videos,user_questions,read_stream,user_posts'}
);
```

Then I'm trying to receive user posts.
    import json
    from time import mktime
    from urllib import urlopen
    from facebook import GraphAPI
    from datetime import datetime

```
ga = GraphAPI()
access_token = ga.get_app_access_token(settings.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,     settings.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+created_time+FROM+stream+ WHERE+source_id=%s+AND+created_time<%d&access_token=%s" % (
social_id,   # user id in facebook, taken from facebook-jssdk
int(mktime((datetime.now().timetuple()))),
access_token
)
data = json.loads(urlopen(url).read())
logger.debug(data)
# {u'data': []}


ga = GraphAPI(access_token)
ga.get_object('/508708815952422/posts/', token=token)
# {u'data': []}
```

Data is always empty...  What am I doing wrong?

**Usefull info**:
**Since "Facebook Login v2.5" permissions require review to work correctly.**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2

Comment: Are you working from an old example? Newly created apps won't have access to FQL, and many of the permissions listed above don't exist in the current version of the API

Comment: I'm working from old and new examples. user_posts permission exists now in graph api: http://i.imgur.com/H1xiO6Z.jpg I've showed FQL only for example - even it isn't working...

Answer (score 5):

You want to know how to get user posts using a python api, right?

I'm using `facebook-sdk` within a django project and I got it to work, like this (Implementation - services/facebook.py):

```
from django.conf import settings
import facebook
import requests

class FacebookFeed:
    token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token'
    params = dict(client_id=settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY, client_secret=settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET,
                  grant_type='client_credentials')

    @classmethod
    def get_posts(cls, user, count=6):
        try:
            token_response = requests.get(url=cls.token_url, params=cls.params)
            access_token = token_response.text.split('=')[1]
            graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
            profile = graph.get_object(user)
            query_string = 'posts?limit={0}'.format(count)
            posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], query_string)
            return posts
        except facebook.GraphAPIError:
            return None
```

**Note:** In my case I need to fetch the access token using the client-credentials flow, making use of the Key and Secret settings, if you're logging users into an app of yours and already have tokens on your side, then ignore the lines:

```
token_response = requests.get(url=cls.token_url, params=cls.params)
access_token = token_response.text.split('=')[1]
```

Usage (views.py):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from app.services.social_networks.facebook import FacebookFeed

def get_facebook_posts(request, user):
    posts = FacebookFeed.get_posts(user=user)
    if not posts:
        return HttpResponse(status=500, content="Can't fetch posts for desired user", content_type="application/json")
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(posts), content_type="application/json")
```

Hope this helps, any problem, please do ask =)

Comment: I always get empty data... It is the problem. In [13]: FacebookFeed.get_posts(user='100000153778906')
Out[13]: {u'data': []}

Comment: Oh ok, I'm using the usernames to retrieve data, so in that case it would not be the id `100000153778906`, but the username associated with that id. I'm in no position of test it right now, but I'll get to it later in the day.

Comment: I think that I've found the reason - my application was not authorized by facebook to use user_posts permissions. I've started approvement process, so don't test. I definitely need that permissions. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't recall needing to start any process of approval (besides registering the app in facebook dev) in order to fetch any data from feeds. Can you provide the link for the documentation of that "approvement process"? Thanks. :)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/requirements#app-details

Comment: Thanks! I'll check later if I that filled in my app, the reason I'm asking for the link is because of pages that are public, like the one you linked, but for some reason don't work (e.g. age restriction in alchool beverage pages) and I want to check if with some config setup I can get it to work.