# getting posts of public pages on Facebook

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get the posts of public pages on Facebook such as bars, clubs etc... and display them on my app?

I am working on a social media app, and I want to post information about real-time events in bars, clubs etc... Is there a way for me to use the posts of these joints from Facebook? Those pages are all public so there is no privacy issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed/) of graph api: `/{user-id}/posts shows only the posts that were published by this person`.

If you need an example, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838434/how-to-get-user-posts-through-facebook-sdk-python-api/32896364#32896364) (implemented in python).

Any question, please do ask.

Comment: So basically I need an access token to do so (Which I can get only from the page by asking them for it) even if the page is set as public on Facebook?

Comment: Yup you'll need a token for public pages on facebook, if you don't want one and you don't care about the UI of your website (if you're doing this to create a FB widget, for instance, you can you their html widget and change the page info dynamically.

Comment: @jlnabais  can you help me for this problem?`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62536699/how-can-i-get-posts-from-public-pages-with-graph-api`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Facebook Graph Api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api).
Here's an example to get all the posts from Stack Overflow page on facebook (You need access token for that):

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/officialstackoverflow/feed?access_token=[YOUR ACCESS TOKEN"
```

The structure of the request is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/[Facebook Entity Id]/feed
```

You can use the [Facebook Graph Explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) for testing and getting temporary access token.

Comment: This works for officialstackoverflow. However I have tried it for other users and the feed field is missing. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve FB pages' posts by date, I use this function:

```
def queryFB (page_id, since_inp, until_inp, access_token=access_token):
    """ retrieve the statuses of one page for a specified time range"""
    # format since = "YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MM:SS+XXXX" (XXXX = time zone difference)
    # format until = "YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MM:SS"
    # format access_token = [app_id] + "|" + [app_secret]       

    # build URL
    base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11"
    node = "/"
    since = "since=" + str(since_inp)
    plus = "&"
    until = "until=" + str(until_inp)
    fields = "fields=id,created_time,updated_time,message,likes.summary(True)"
    token = "access_token=%s" % access_token
    url = base + node + page_id + node + "posts?" + since + plus + until + plus + fields + plus + token

    print(url)
```

(Of course, this will then need to be amended to use the output.)