# How can I get posts from public pages with Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have Graph API Facebook. As shown as when I get my Posts that work. but when I get public page that not wok and get error  `(#100) Pages Public Content Access requires either app secret proof or an app token`. I generate token with all permissions but not work.

My posts(worked):
[image: Work for my posts]

JasonStatham posts(not work):
[image: not work]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Comment: @CBroe  I read this link, but I got worse because it linked to different parts.

Comment: You will need to submit your app for approval of this feature, if you want to be able to read public data from pages you do not have admin access to.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via official GraphQL QPI, in specific the [/page-post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-public-content-access) endpoint.

There is also [a good example here](https://github.com/ameyyadav09/fb-bot/blob/master/scraper.py) of how to do that with Python.
However, you need to keep in mind that in order to use this API you need to have a Facebook Application with 'Page Public Content Access'.
To get that permission your app **must** be a verified Business app.